# How to choose particular row containing more than one value in pandas series?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have created a pandas `series` applying `groupby` function and `value_counts()`. I want to choose a row which has more than one value.

```
Input:
Name                         Value
A                             201         
B                             219
B                             219         
C                             704   
D                             222      
D                             219
ex = ex.groupby("Value")
ex = ex["Name"].value_counts()

Output:
 Value  Name    
  201    A      3
  219    B      2
         D      1
  704    C      1
  222    D      1
```

I want to choose `value` `219` having multiple `Name` `B` and  `D`.

Comment: Can you explain in more detail: `I want to choose a row which has multiple values from the series`? What precisely is your logic?

Comment: I was not able to express properly in words hence gave the example. Table is example of grouby function output. I want logic to choose B from the given table. Here be has value 2 and 3.

Comment: So is the dataframe you displayed an input or output? Can you construct your input dataframe from scratch, e.g. `df = pd.DataFrame([[..., ...], [.., ...]], columns=['a', 'b'])`..?

Comment: I have updated the question hope the requirement is clear.

Comment: Thank you, *now* much clearer!

Comment: So what is expected output? `219` or `B` and `D` ?

Comment: both `Name` and `Value`

Comment: @someone - Check edited answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think need [`DataFrame.duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html) by both columns:

```
df = df[df.duplicated(['Name','Value'], keep=False)]
print (df)
  Name  Value
1    B    219
2    B    219
```

But if need output of counted values filter by level `Value`:

```
s = df.groupby("Value")["Name"].value_counts()
print (s)

df1 = s[s.index.get_level_values('Value').duplicated(keep=False)].reset_index(name='count')
print (df1)
   Value Name  count
0    219    B      2
1    219    D      1
```

Another solution is create `DataFrame` by [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.reset_index.html) first:

```
df2 = df.groupby("Value")["Name"].value_counts().reset_index(name='count')
print (df2)
   Value Name  count
0    201    A      1
1    219    B      2
2    219    D      1
3    222    D      1
4    704    C      1

df1 = df2[df2['Value'].duplicated(keep=False)]
print (df1)
   Value Name  count
1    219    B      2
2    219    D      1
```

Answer (score -1):

There is no need to for additional `groupby`.

You can use `pd.Series.duplicated` with your *original* dataframe:

```
res = df[df['Value'].duplicated(keep=False)]

print(res)

  Name  Value
1    B    219
3    D    219

print(res['Name'].tolist())

['B', 'D']
```